# Is there a way to have a stored procedure parameter that is both input and output in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm re-writing a program which was developed in Delphi and I want to code it into C#. The old developer has used a stored procedure which I want to use it like the old version. In the SP's parameters, there are some output parameters but one of those in which has been used as an input parameter too.
So I've to set a value to it and also get the output value.

I tried to code like this:

```
int MyValue = 4;
SqlCommand MyCom = new SqlCommand();
MyCom.Connection = (SomeConnectionObject);
MyCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
MyCom.CommandText = "MySP";

MyCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1_Output", MyValue);
MyCom.Parameters["@Parameter1_Output"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

In the executed query (Profiler) value set to the parameter is 0 while I have set it to 4.

Comment: `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`?

Comment: This one should be input not output

Comment: as Dmitry said check `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`

Comment: Indeed, there is. You almost got it. Check the [ParameterDirection enumeration values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.parameterdirection?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: "In the executed query (Profiler) value set to the parameter is 0 while I have set it to 4." If you say it is `Output` the value is not sent to the database, it will only read whatever you assign it in your SQL. Thats the reason in the profiler you see a "0" (typical not assigned int value)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Right answer. will you please post your comment as an answer? I want to check it :)

Comment: @Shaho: OK, let me quote the manual as an answer, not comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if we have a look at [ParameterDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.parameterdirection?view=netframework-4.8) `enum` we'll find

> **Fields**
>
> ...
>
> `InputOutput` `3` The parameter is capable of *both input and output*.

(italic is mine). That's why

```
MyCom.Parameters["@Parameter1_Output"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```